# SAP HANA Vora failing to see the table contents in Scala

Tags: scala, vora

Failing to see the data in Scala using Vora.

VORA: 1.2
Spark: 1.5.2 / Spark controller: 1.5.8

The hdfs file "content" showing fine.

**hdfs dfs -cat /user/vora/XXXXXXXX/part-00000**
AB05,560
CD06,340
EF07,590
GH08,230

**Table showing up fine in the "show datasourcestables" command**

scala> vc.sql(s"""SHOW DATASOURCETABLES USING com.sap.spark.vora""".stripMargin ).show
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwCiZ.jpg)

**Show table is failing in Scala**
scala> vc.sql("select * from VVCSV").show

scala> vc.sql("select * from VVCSV").show

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: VVCSV
>          at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>          at >org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:139)
>          at >org.apache.spark.sql.extension.ExtendableSQLContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(ExtendableSQLContext.scala:52)
>          at >org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:203)
>          at >?>org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:203)
>          at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)

Answer (score 0):

Command `show datasourcetables` is deprecated with Vora1.2 and been replaced by `show tables using com.sap.spark.vora`. However that command is only showing what is persisted in the Vora catalog. To load the tables in the current Spark context (e.g. after restarting the spark-shell) you need to run the `register tables` command:

```
vc.sql("register all tables using com.sap.spark.vora").show
```

To check what is in the current Spark context you can use the `show tables` command (without the 'using' clause). For more details you can check the [Vora Developer Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Developer_Guide_en.pdf) and the Spark documentation.